# Implementing Deferred Deep Linking in iOS App

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

**Question:**

I have an existing iOS app, and I want to implement deferred deep linking. The goal is to provide a URL or link to customers that, when clicked, should:

1. Direct users to the app if it's already installed.
2. Open the App Store to download the app if it's not installed.

I'm not sure how to achieve this. How can one URL handle both cases (app installed and not installed)? Could someone provide a general way of achieving this?

I have seen tutorials and read the Apple doc, but haven't understood the general way of achieving this.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Re universal links, I’d suggest checking out [Supporting universal links in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app/) and [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/). And if you’ve attempted that and failed, show us what you tried and what went wrong. It’s a bit much for us to outline all the steps (and there are plenty of S.O. answers and offsite tutorials that explain the process).

Comment: @Rob, Can I implement it using Custom URL Schemes as I just want the customer to redirect to the app if installed otherwise redirect to Appstore to download. And I want a general flow of steps to do, not an exact solution, just a high-level flow.

Comment: I have different Build Schemes in my Project, so how can I manage all the schemes?
Do I need to create an Associated Domain for each and place it in the AASA file?

Comment: I have read a lot about it, but still, the picture of the complete process is not clear in my mind, A few doubts also I have:- 1. Who will create the HTTP link that will be shared with customers? 2. Where the AASA file will be hosted and how? Our app doesn't have any web app, only iOS App. 3. What will be the structure of the Associated Domain, Can I give any URL in the associated domain?

Comment: Also, I read about custom URLs and Universal Links, now I got confused between the two. My task is just to if the user has the app, open the app, otherwise redirect the user to the appstore to open the app. Now say we can use Custom URLs for this, some say custom URLs cannot handle the fallback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256641/discussion-between-rob-and-abhistin).

Comment: Hi @Rob, I Implemented the Universal Links, while clicking on the URL opens the app(App installed already on the device), I want, if the app is not installed, while clicking on the link, the user should be redirected to AppStore, How to do this?

Comment: The idea is that whatever the URL is, you create a page on your website with the same URL. That page is either a “call to action” page with a link to the App Store or you might set up that page to do one that automatically redirects the web browser directly to the store. The only trick is that if you want to do the automatic redirect, you might want a URL that doesn’t already exist on your web site. E.g. if your domain is example.com, and your app is called “Foo”, then you might make the link be something like https://example.com/Foo or set up a subdomain https://foo.example.com.

Comment: Hi @Rob, Two things still are not clear to me.
1. In my projects, I have 5 different build schemes for different customers. Now how one URL can handle the opening of different apps?
2. Let's say my domain is www.example.com, I have hosted my AASA on the domain, but how to handle redirection to Appstore?
I have a few queries, if you could please start the inbox again.

Comment: Re different builds for different customers, I assume you mean you have different apps in the store for each customer. That means, you would generally have (a) different bundle identifiers for each app and (b) different universal link URLs for each, too. By convention, each bundle identifier is generally a reverse DNS of the associated universal link URL. Anyway, once you have separate universal link URLs (whether separate domains of each customer or separate subdomains on your top level domain, is up to you), you would have separate AASAs for each, linking to the corresponding app.

Comment: What I have - A single Xcode Project, having 5 different builds(each having its own bundle identifier) for different customers. What I did- I added all 5 different bundle identifiers under one AASA file and hosted it on the website's root. What I want - Provide links to customers, if the app not installed, redirect them to app store to download the app.
Could you please start a chat room, I can tell you there in detail.

Comment: We can [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256906/chat-between-rob-and-abhistinuniversal-links)